# How to make changes in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use angularJS Dropdown Multiselect from this [link](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/).

The problem is that selected items stored in this format(as array of objects):

```
[{"id": 3},{"id": 2},{"id": 1}]
```

While I need to store selected values in this format(as array on int's):

```
[3,2,1]
```

I tried to figure out how I have to change the code in [directive](https://rawgit.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/master/src/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js) to make 
the change above but I did not succeed the directive didn't work properly after I made changes.

Any idea how can I store only array of id's not array of objects?

Comment: You might get more answers if you show the code that you tried, and explain what went wrong. Otherwise people have to click that link and troubleshoot w/out any of the knowledge you've already gained from your troubleshooting.

Comment: The code is inside the questuion(links)

Comment: It looks like the second accordion in that link (titled basic settings example) changes to code to display by id. Maybe I'm not understanding your question entirely, Do you want to display just the id? Or do you want to store only the id's?

Comment: @Sunde,I want to store only the id's!!!I am sorry if the question not properly formulated